# check if all elements of an array have the same value in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift

Is there a function in Swift that checks whether all elements of an array have the same value? In my case, it's an array of type `Int`. I know I can iterate over it using a simple for loop I was just wondering if there is something that is built in and quicker.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Any method must iterate over all elements until a different element is found:

```
func allEqualUsingLoop<T : Equatable>(array : [T]) -> Bool {
    if let firstElem = array.first {
        for elem in array {
            if elem != firstElem {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Instead of an explicit loop you can use the `contains()` function:

```
func allEqualUsingContains<T : Equatable>(array : [T]) -> Bool {
    if let firstElem = array.first {
        return !contains(array, { $0 != firstElem })
    }
    return true
}
```

If the array elements are `Hashable` (such as `Int`) then you can
create a `Set` (available since Swift 1.2) from the array elements and check if it has exactly one element.

```
func allEqualUsingSet<T : Hashable>(array : [T]) -> Bool {
    let uniqueElements = Set(array)
    return count(uniqueElements) <= 1
}
```

A quick benchmarking test revealed that the "contains" method is much faster than the "set" method
for an array of 1,000,000 integers, in particular if the elements are
*not* all equal. This make sense because `contains()` returns as soon
as a non-matching element is found, whereas `Set(array)` always 
traverses the entire array.

Also the "contains" methods is equally fast or slightly faster than an explicit loop.

Here is some simple benchmarking code. Of course the results can vary
with the array size, the number of different elements and the elements data type.

```
func measureExecutionTime<T>(title: String,  @noescape f : (() -> T) ) -> T {
    let start = NSDate()
    let result = f()
    let end = NSDate()
    let duration = end.timeIntervalSinceDate(start)
    println("\(title) \(duration)")
    return result
}

var array = [Int](count: 1_000_000, repeatedValue: 1)
array[500_000] = 2

let b1 = measureExecutionTime("using loop    ") {
    return allEqualUsingLoop(array)
}

let b2 = measureExecutionTime("using contains") {
    allEqualUsingContains(array)
}

let b3 = measureExecutionTime("using set     ") {
    allEqualUsingSet(array)
}
```

Results (on a MacBook Pro, Release configuration):

```
using loop     0.000651001930236816
using contains 0.000567018985748291
using set      0.0344770550727844
```

With `array[1_000] = 2` the results are

```
using loop     9.00030136108398e-06
using contains 2.02655792236328e-06
using set      0.0306439995765686
```

---

**Update for Swift 2/Xcode 7:** Due to various changes in the Swift
syntax, the function is now written as

```
func allEqual<T : Equatable>(array : [T]) -> Bool {
    if let firstElem = array.first {
        return !array.dropFirst().contains { $0 != firstElem }
    }
    return true
}
```

But you can now also define it as an extension method for arrays:

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func allEqual() -> Bool {
        if let firstElem = first {
            return !dropFirst().contains { $0 != firstElem }
        }
        return true
    }
}

print([1, 1, 1].allEqual()) // true
print([1, 2, 1].allEqual()) // false
```

Comment: Was trying the same...  compiler checked ;-)

Comment: If you’re interested in another one to try, you could use `equal` and `Repeat`: `array.first.map { equal(array, Repeat(count: array.count, repeatedValue: $0)) } ?? true` (it’s slower)

Comment: @AirspeedVelocity: It is slower, but not drastically: With `array[500_000] = 2` I measure 0.001789 sec and with `array[1_000] = 2` 3.99e-06 sec.

Comment: Yeah it’ll be the extra overhead of it checking they are the same length (even though that doesn’t actually matter) I expect.

Comment: That's one fine answer! Thanks

Comment: @MartinR Could you write an `extension Array` for checking if only `several elements of an array` have the same value?

Comment: If the max value and min value were cached and/or computed while the array was filled, this is unbeatable: ints.max() == ints.min()

Answer (score 60):

With Swift 5, you can use one of the four following ways in order to tests if all elements of an array are equal.

---

### #1. Using `Array`'s [`allSatisfy(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2994715-allsatisfy) method

`allSatisfy(_:)` returns a Boolean value indicating whether every element of a sequence satisfies a given predicate. You can set the predicate to test if all elements of the array are equal:

```
let array = [1, 1, 1]

let hasAllItemsEqual = array.dropFirst().allSatisfy({ $0 == array.first })
print(hasAllItemsEqual) // prints: true
```

```
let array = [1, 1, 3]

let hasAllItemsEqual = array.dropFirst().allSatisfy({ $0 == array.first })
print(hasAllItemsEqual) // prints: false
```

```
let array = [Int]()

let hasAllItemsEqual = array.dropFirst().allSatisfy({ $0 == array.first })
print(hasAllItemsEqual) // prints: true
```

---

### #2. Using `Array`'s [`reduce(_:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2298686-reduce) method

As an alternative to `allSatisfy(_:)`, you can use `reduce(_:_:)`:

```
let array = [1, 1, 1]

let hasAllItemsEqual = array.dropFirst().reduce(true) { (partialResult, element) in
    return partialResult && element == array.first
}
print(hasAllItemsEqual) // prints: true
```

```
let array = [1, 1, 3]

let hasAllItemsEqual = array.dropFirst().reduce(true) { (partialResult, element) in
    return partialResult && element == array.first
}
print(hasAllItemsEqual) // prints: false
```

```
let array = [Int]()

let hasAllItemsEqual = array.dropFirst().reduce(true) { (partialResult, element) in
    return partialResult && element == array.first
}
print(hasAllItemsEqual) // prints: true
```

---

### #3. Using [`elementsEqual(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2853688-elementsequal) method

`elementsEqual(_:)` returns a Boolean value indicating whether two sequences contain the same elements in the same order. Therefore you can create a new collection by repeating the first element of the initial array and compare the former with the latter:

```
let array = [1, 1, 1]

precondition(!array.isEmpty)
let repeated = repeatElement(array[0], count: array.count)

let hasAllItemsEqual = array.elementsEqual(repeated)
print(hasAllItemsEqual) // prints: true
```

```
let array = [1, 1, 3]

precondition(!array.isEmpty)
let repeated = repeatElement(array[0], count: array.count)

let hasAllItemsEqual = array.elementsEqual(repeated)
print(hasAllItemsEqual) // prints: false
```

---

### #4. Using `Set`'s [`init(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/3128846-init) initalizer

If all elements of an array are equal, creating a set from this array should result in the set having only one element:

```
let array = [1, 1, 1]

let set = Set(array)
let hasAllItemsEqual = set.count <= 1
print(hasAllItemsEqual) // prints: true
```

```
let array = [1, 1, 3]

let set = Set(array)
let hasAllItemsEqual = set.count <= 1
print(hasAllItemsEqual) // prints: false
```

```
let array = [Int]()

let set = Set(array)
let hasAllItemsEqual = set.count <= 1
print(hasAllItemsEqual) // prints: true
```

Answer (score 17):

Soliution for Swift 4.2/Xcode 10:

```
let arr = [1, 1, 1, 1]
let allItemsEqual = arr.dropLast().allSatisfy { $0 == arr.last }
print(allItemsEqual)
```

If your current version of Xcode is prior to 10.0 you can find the function `allSatisfy` of `ArraySlice` in [Xcode9to10Preparation](https://github.com/RomanPodymov/Xcode9to10Preparation). You can install this library with CocoaPods.

Comment: You don't really need `dropLast()`.

Comment: @Sulthan It is important to add `dropLast()` here. In my example if I will remove `dropLast()` the block passed to `allSatisfy` will be called 4 times, but now it is calling only 3 times, and result is the same.

Comment: You don't need it. Complexity is the same

Comment: @Lirik You can add your own answer and explain why there should not be `dropLast()`.

Comment: I understand its redundant to check if the last object equals to itself, but going over the array 3 times or 4 times has the same Complexity in CS terms, so it doesn't really matter.

Answer (score 1):

```swift
let ints: [Int] = [1, 1, 1, 1]
print(ints.max() == ints.min())
```

If you have float buffers or if you already have an array of floats (or you think converting to floats beforehand is convenient):

```swift
import Accelerate

// [...]

// let floats = ints.map({ Double($0) })
print(vDSP.minimum(floats) == vDSP.maximum(floats))
```

Comment: I think, this is the best solution for int array. Comparing min and max values is really good idea.