# Swift 2 Logical AND(&) Operator

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I am new to programming and trying to find a simpler way to do this:

```
if state[0] != 0 && state[1] != 0 && state[2] != 0 && state[3] != 0 && state[4] != 0 && state[5] != 0 && state[6] != 0 && state[7] != 0 && state[8] != 0 {
                    gameOverLabel.text = "It's a tie."
                    gameOverLabel.hidden = false
                    active = false
    }
```

I tried the code below but it reacted like a OR rather than a AND.

```
if state[0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8] != 0 {
                        gameOverLabel.text = "It's a tie."
                        gameOverLabel.hidden = false
                        active = false
        }
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Wouldn't `0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8` equal 0?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if all elements of an array have the same value in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588158/check-if-all-elements-of-an-array-have-the-same-value-in-swift)

Comment: Is 8 the [state] length?

Comment: Swift doesn't care what you WANT. It's a programming language. It has rules. Learn the rules, follow the rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your intention is to check if *all* array elements
are different from zero, the easiest approach would be

```
if !state.contains(0) { ... }
```

---

Your code

```
if state[0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8] != 0 { ... }
```

does not work
as intended because here the bitwise AND `0&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8`
is computed first (with result zero), so that is equivalent to

```
if state[0] != 0 { ... }
```

Comment: if !state.contains(0)     should be enough

Comment: @user3441734: Sorry, I don't get you. That is exactly what I suggested.

Comment: Thanks Martin, exactly what I'm looking for :)

Answer (score 0):

```
let state = [0,1,2,0,4,5,6,7]
if state.filter{$0 != 0}.count > 0 {
                    gameOverLabel.text = "It's a tie."
                    gameOverLabel.hidden = false
                    active = false
}
```

Try this one

Comment: Thanks, a different approach :)

Answer (score 0):

### The general case with an `Array` of indices

1. The short version

   ```
   let indices = [4,2,9,6,5,3,8,0]

   if !indices.contains({ state[$0] == 0 }) {
       // ...
   }
   ```
2. A second version which only shows the possibilities of Swift:

   ```
   if !indices.lazy.map{ state[$0] }.contains(0) {
       // ...
   }
   ```

   The `lazy` is used since otherwise `map` would apply the closure to all indices whereas `lazy` applies it on average only to half the elements (`contains` determines the number of executions of the closure).

   **Note**: There is probably no performance improvement for a small amount of indices. The first version is certainly (ever so slightly) faster.

### A specific range of indices

1. Just use the approach above with

   ```
   let indices = 5...9
   ```
2. Or directly operate on the sub sequence of `Array` which is `ArraySlice`.

   **Side note**: Even though it seems that `ArraySlice` (return type of `Array[Range<Int>]`) is a value type, internally it is a reference type (like `Array`) which only copies itself on mutation. In addition `ArraySlice` is only a view into the array (as long none of them is mutated). So it could be even faster than the first approach.

   ```
   if !state[24...42].contains(0) {
       // ...
   }
   ```