# Checking that all Array elements match value

Tags: ios, swift, set

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29588187/1187415) as the answer to a different question. It is used to determine if all elements of an Array match.

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {
    func allEqual() -> Bool {
        if let firstElem = first {
            return !dropFirst().contains { $0 != firstElem }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

I tried to refactor it so that, it was a Set instead of Array, and a value could be passed in, so you could check if every element of a Set matched the passed in value. But I got no where fast. I think because I also tried to make the value a generic. Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Ahhhh... okay, I guess Array is the way to go!

Comment: you could simplify your method`return !dropFirst().contains { $0 != first }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking if all element of an array are equal to a given value
can be done slightly shorter with

```
extension Array where Element : Equatable {

    func allEqualTo(value: Element) -> Bool {
        return !contains { $0 != value }
    }

}
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why wouldn't `return contains { $0 == value }` work?

Comment: @RyJ: That would return true if *any* (at least one) array element is equal to the given value. The question here was how to check if *all* array elements are equal to the given value.

Answer (score 4):

A Set is not like an Array. For one thing, a Set is unordered, while an Array is ordered. Even more important, by definition, all Set elements have *different values from one another*. Therefore they *cannot* all match the *same* value. (Except, of course, in the trivial degenerate case where the Set has exactly one element!)

Answer (score 0):

So after realizing that Sets should only have unique values, and that I should use an Array instead, I modified the above to accept a value:

```
func allEqual(value: Element) -> Bool {
    if let first = first {
        if contains(value) {
            return !dropFirst().contains { $0 != first }
        }
        return false
    }
    return false
}
```