# How do I check a condition for every element in an array?

Tags: arrays, swift, loops, if-statement, control-flow

I have a piece of code that I want to run only if certain conditions are true for every element in an array. Currently, I have to know the length of the array for any of the code to work, but my end goal is to have it work for an array of any length.

My current code:

```
if (rand[0] == someInt && rand[1] == someInt && . . . && rand[n] == someInt) {

    *do some things*

}
```

I want this to work not knowing the length of `rand`.

Comment: Use `forEach`: http://swiftdoc.org/v2.2/type/Array/#func-foreach_

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if all elements of an array have the same value in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29588158/check-if-all-elements-of-an-array-have-the-same-value-in-swift)

Answer (score 5):

In Swift 3, with `first(where:)`, this is very simple:

```
extension Sequence {
    func allPass(predicate: (Iterator.Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        return first(where: { !predicate($0) }) == nil
    }
}
```

In Swift 2.2, it's similar:

```
extension SequenceType {
    func allPass(predicate: (Generator.Element) -> Bool) -> Bool {
        for element in self {
            if !predicate(element) { return false }
        }
        return true
    }
}
```

In either case, these immediately return false when they find the first failing element.

Answer (score 3):

A common implementation is to use the basic transformation to `contains` and two negations:

```
// all equal to someInt <=> there is none that is not equal to someInt
if !(rand.contains { $0 != someInt }) {
  ...
}
```

or

```
extension Sequence {
    public func allSatisfy(where predicate: (Self.Iterator.Element) throws -> Bool) rethrows -> Bool {
        return try !self.contains { element throws -> Bool in
            return try !predicate(element)
        }
    }
}

if (rand.allSatisfy { $0 == someInt }) {
  ...
}
```

However, this method has been finally added to Swift standard lib in Swift 4.2 (Xcode 10+, see [SE-207](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0207-containsOnly.md)) therefore there is no need for extensions.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to `reduce`, you may want to learn about `filter`, which can be helpful if you care about the "else" case or measuring how close you are to success. For example:

```
let matches = rand.filter { $0 == someInt }

if rand.count == matches.count {
    print("there were \(matches.count) matches")
    // do some things
} else {
    print("there were only \(matches.count) of \(rand.count) total possible matches")
}
```

Comment: arrayName.filter { $0.propertyName == true } <- very nice! Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
if rand.reduce(true, combine: {$0 && $1 == someInt})
{
    print("do some thing")
}
```

The reduce function lets you supply an initial value and a closure that maps a value of that type and an element of the array to a value of the same type as your initial value, then it applies that function to each value in the array. So this just ANDs the results of comparing each element of the array to your desired value. Conceptually, this is equivalent to what you originally wrote.

If you haven't seen $0 and $1 they can be confusing; they are just the arguments to the anonymous closure you supplied to reduce, in this case $0 is a boolean value, and $1 an element of your array.