# How to build a Swift function that compares indefinite number of strings?

Tags: swift, function

I want to be able to pass in an indefinite number of strings (varargs) into a function and get returned whether or not they are all the same string.

Here's what I've done so far - but I need some assistance going further:

```
func compareSymbols(symbols: String...) -> Bool {
    var symbolsAreEqual = false
    for symbol in symbols {

    }
    return symbolsAreEqual
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [check if all elements of an array have the same value in Swift](http://stackoverflow.com/q/29588158/2976878)

Comment: Not quite a duplicate since this is about a function with a variadic parameter .  I have linked to @Martin's excellent answer in my answer.

Comment: @vacawama: It does not really make a difference, because variadic parameters are represented as an array inside  the function.

Comment: @MartinR, while that is true, I feel marking something as a duplicate means that they asked the exact same question.  Someone asking about variadic parameters shouldn't be expected to think to search for arrays.  It is a subtle distinction I admit.

Comment: When asking questions here, please indicate in what way you are stuck. You've said you need some assistance, but it is good to expand on that. What do you believe you need? What research did you do? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put them in a `Set` (removing duplicates) and check if the resulting set contains only one element:

```
func compareSymbols(symbols: String...) -> Bool {
    return Set(symbols).count == 1
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's a version that will quit as soon as it finds a different symbol:

```
func compareSymbols(symbols: String...) -> Bool {
    if let first = symbols.first {
        for symbol in symbols.dropFirst() {
            if symbol != first {
                return false
            }
        }
    }
    return true
}

compareSymbols(symbols: "a", "a", "a")  // true    
compareSymbols(symbols: "a", "b")       // false
compareSymbols(symbols: "a")            // true
```

---

Variadic parameters (like `symbols: String...`) are represented as arrays inside of the function.
@MartinR answers a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29588187/1630618) about arrays.  He talks about the performance implications of using an explicit loop vs. `Set` vs. `contains`.